# SQL: Contador de registros com agrupamento de dados de campos diferentes

Tags: sql, hibernate, postgresql

Estou com uma dificuldade para construir uma SQL.
tenho uma tabela **endereco** com os campos strings **rua** e **cruzamento**.
Preciso contar o números de registros que possuem o mesmo cruzamento e agrupa-los
Exemplo:

```
id | rua | Cruzamento
1  | Rua Brasil | Rua Parana 
2  | Rua Parana | Rua Brasil
3  | Rua Brasil |
4  | Rua Parana |
5  | Rua Brasil | Rua Parana
6  | Rua Parana | Rua São Paulo
```

A consulta deve retornar:

```
cont | descricao
3 | Rua Brasil - Rua Parana
1 | Rua Parana - Rua São Paulo
```

Alguém pode dar uma luz?
Obrigado.

Comment: A combinação de tags da sua pergunta é um pouco ambígua;  Você quer um SQL para postgre ou um HQL para hibernate?

Comment: Você quer que o script SQL reconheça que Rua Brasil Rua Parana e Rua Parana Rua Brasil se trata do mesmo cruzamento?

Comment: tanto faz genos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segundo a questão: "Preciso contar o números de registros que possuem o mesmo cruzamento e agrupa-lo"

Então teríamos:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(id), rua || ' - ' || cruzamento As descricao_Rua_Cruzamento
FROM endereco 
WHERE rua ilike '%' || rua || '%' 
AND cruzamento ilike '%' || cruzamento || '%'  
GROUP BY rua,cruzamento
ORDER BY COUNT(id) DESC ;

# count | descricao_rua_cruzamento
# 2 | Rua Brasil - Rua Parana
# 1 | Rua Parana - Rua Brasil
# 1 | Rua Parana - Rua São Paulo
```

Assim estou contando os registros que possuem o mesmo cruzamento. Segundo sua questão.
Visto que Rua Brasil cruza com Rua Parana duas vezes, já a outra Rua, a Rua Parana que cruza com a Rua Brasil uma única vez na base de dados. 
Agora se for "o script SQL reconheça que Rua Brasil Rua Parana e Rua Parana Rua Brasil se trata do mesmo cruzamento" Seria outra questão, não? Faz-se necessário modificações no script acima para atender a segunda questão.

Comment: "o script SQL reconheça que Rua Brasil Rua Parana e Rua Parana Rua Brasil se trata do mesmo cruzamento"
É exatamente essa a minha dificuldade. Eu já havia chegado a essa SQL anteriormente. Quais seriam as modificações necessárias?

Comment: Resolvi utilizando uma padronização em meu banco, onde quando possuir um cruzamento, ele sempre estará em ordem alfabética. 

Assim sempre estará "Rua Brasil - Rua Parana"

Comment: Parabéns! E valeu por postar a solução para registro.